# Change HTML textbox values with console code

Tags: java, html, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

First of all, I must say that I am less than noob in this field.
I've been sitting on a problem all morning.

What I want to do:
I often need to change prices (200+ rows) in a table on the web interface. To improve this, I already have an Excel VBA file to calculate the correct values, now I want to remove the manual input of the 200+ rows in the browser.
I only need to change it "visually" as I can save the values after.

I thought this could hopefully be done with the inspection console in Chrome.
Manually it works if I change the value in the code (red bordered value="3.33" to whatever I want).
Now I'm trying to find the right code to change it in the console without clicking in the code.
I tried it already with

> document.getElementById('LAYOUT_DONNEES_PRIX-2-16-cell').value='1,00';

or

> document.getElementByName('LAYOUT_DONNEES_PRIX-2-16').value='1,00';

but without success. (left Screenshots).
You can see document.getElementsById returns "null", document.getElementsByName returns the NodeList.

As I already told you I am a total noob on this, so hopefully you can easily tell me what parameter I need to choose.

Please let me know if you need any additional information of the code or anything else.

Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZa9f.png)

Comment: Spelling: `document.getElementById ` returns ONE element if there is ONE element with that ID. `document.getElementsByName` returns a nodelist and the nodelist[0] is the first by that NAME

Comment: I suggest you use `document.querySelector("[name='LAYOUT_DONNEESPRIX_2_6']")` if you want to access only the first field by that name OR `document.querySelectorAll("[name='LAYOUT_DONNEESPRIX_2_6']").forEach(prix => { do something with the field or the field.value here })` if you have more elements with the same name

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var newValue = '5.00'; // Replace '3.33' with the desired new value

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="3.33"]');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].value = newValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:

> document.getElementsByName('LAYOUT_DONNEES_PRIX-2-16')[0].value='1,2'
> document.getElementsByName('LAYOUT_DONNEES_PRIX-3-16')[0].value='2,11'

works great to change the values

Thank you all